# How to handle a few TextInput by single handler in React Native without lambda function?

Tags: javascript, react-native, lambda, textinput, eventhandler

I need to handle a few inputs by single event handler in React Native app, but not to use lambda function, because it is forbidden in my app. With lambda function you can just sent the second parameter and it could be like this:

```
<TextInput
    placeholder = 'email'
    onSubmitEditing ={Keyboard.dismiss}
    onChangeText = {(text) => { this.handleTwoInputs(text, 'email'); }}
    autoCorrect = {false}
/>
<TextInput
    placeholder = 'name'
    onSubmitEditing ={Keyboard.dismiss}
    onChangeText = {(text) => { this.handleTwoInputs(text, 'name'); }}
    autoCorrect = {false}
/>
handleTwoInputs = (text, type) => {
  if(type === 'name'){
    this.inputName = text;
  } else {
   this.inputEmail = text;
 }
}
```

But how to do it without lambda function?

Comment: jocoders did you have time to check my last edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use an arrow function:

```
<TextInput
    placeholder = 'email'
    onSubmitEditing ={Keyboard.dismiss}
    onChangeText = {function(text) { this.handleTwoInputs(text, 'email'); }}
    autoCorrect = {false}
/>

<TextInput
    placeholder = 'name'
    onSubmitEditing ={Keyboard.dismiss}
    onChangeText = {function(text) { this.handleTwoInputs(text, 'name'); }}
    autoCorrect = {false}
/>
```

EDIT:

OK I think I misunderstood the question. What you want to achieve is possible with [`onChange`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onchangetext) instead of `onChangeText`:

```
<TextInput
    name = 'email_input'
    placeholder = 'email'
    onSubmitEditing ={Keyboard.dismiss}
    onChangeText = {handleTwoInputs}
    autoCorrect = {false}
/>

<TextInput
    name = 'name_input'
    placeholder = 'name'
    onSubmitEditing ={Keyboard.dismiss}
    onChangeText = {handleTwoInputs}
    autoCorrect = {false}
/>

handleTwoInputs = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    const { eventCount, target, text } = nativeEvent

    if (target.name === 'name_input') {
      this.inputName = text;
    } else {
      this.inputEmail = text;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, but in my app i use MVC pattern, where my logic i keep separate from the view, it means i can not put function inside of the onChangeText property directly to TextInput component, and it is not good practice to do it, i can just sent handler there

Comment: So what you want is to pass a the same handler to all the inputs but somehow they behave differently. I'm afraid this is not possible...
Let me say that this has nothing to do with MVC but with how JS works. A handler is not logic, it's just an anonymous function you're using.
Eventually you will have to pass the second argument. Maybe you create a custom Input that does it internally but it is the same. Let me add some examples to my answer but I guess you already know this.

Comment: Man you are right, i did not find any solution and decided to use lambda function, thank you so much

Comment: Look at the last answer tho :)

Comment: Cool! That's what i need! Thank you so much :)))